# How to write swift 3 method with throws statement and return value that can be used in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

Below Swift 3 method is translated into Objective C like:

```
func doSomething(param: String) throws // Swift 3

- (BOOL)doSomething:(NSString * _Nonnull)param error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error; // Translated Objective C
```

Then, how can I write a method with both throws and a return type?

```
func doSomething(param: String) throws -> Int // Swift 3

// Error: Never translated into Objective C
```

I know flow should not be handled by NSError object. It just contains information about an error. And that's why there's a BOOL return type to let us know the invocation is succeeded without any problem.

Then how can I handle a method with both throws statement and return type? Is there a standard way to handle this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of reporting success or failure in Objective-C is
to return the boolean value `NO` or a `nil` object pointer,
as documented in
[Using and Creating Error Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html):

> **Important:** Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the method.
>   Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in the Cocoa error 
>   domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the method indicates failure
>   by directly returning nil or NO, you should always check that the return
>   value is nil or NO before attempting to do anything with the NSError object.

So you can return a instance of an object

```
func doSomething(param: String) throws -> NSNumber
```

which is translated to

```
- (NSNumber * _Nullable)doSomethingWithParam:(NSString * _Nonnull)param error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;
```

and returns `nil` if an error is thrown, or return a boolean and
pass other values back by reference

```
func doSomething(param: String, value: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) throws
```

which is mapped to

```
- (BOOL)doSomethingWithParam:(NSString * _Nonnull)param value:(NSInteger * _Nonnull)value error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (int) doSomething:(NString *)param error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

Comment: Not my case. I want to write code in Swift not Objective C. And @Martin's solution is works.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to handle this if you can modify the throwable object.

If you can put up an enum for the errors, and annotate the error enum with @objc than the automatic bridge header will convert it to NSError like mentioned here before.

For example:

```
@objc enum MyError:Int, Error{
    case AnError
    case AnotherError
}
```

And your throwing swift method:

```
public class MyClass:NSObject{

    public func throwAnError() throws {
        throw MyError.AnotherError
    }

    public func callMe(){
        print("Someone called!")
    }

}
```

Will be converted by the auto bridging process to:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC13ErrorHandling7MyClass")
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (BOOL)throwAnErrorAndReturnError:(NSError * __nullable * __null_unspecified)error;
- (void)callMe;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Taken from the bottom of [this excellent blog](https://www.uraimo.com/2015/11/03/error-handling-from-objective-c-to-swift-2-and-back/) post which is relevant to this question.